# DOMDocument not working

Tags: php

I want to find all images in the html string like in the code below.
Why all results are null in this example (except node name which gives 'img')? I want to display the image html string for each image.

```
 $html = '<img src=\'dasdasdasd.jpg\' >';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$els = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ( $els as $el ) {
    $nodeName = strtolower($el->nodeName);
    $nodetext =  strtolower($el->textContent);
    $nodeval = strtolower($el->nodeValue);
        var_dump($nodeName);
        var_dump($nodetext);
        var_dump($nodeval);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [scraping all images from a website using DOMDocument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895773/scraping-all-images-from-a-website-using-domdocument)

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895773/scraping-all-images-from-a-website-using-domdocument

Comment: there are different issues in these questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that node doesn't have any value or text...

What you want is the attribute:

```
$src = $el->getAttribute("src");
var_dump($src); //dasdasdasd.jpg
```

---

As commented, if you need the whole XML, you can use

```
$xml = $dom->savexml($el);
echo $xml;
```

Comment: yes but I need to get the whole image code like "<img src="image.jpg" >"

Comment: That would be `echo $dom->savexml($el);`